# Getting all branches with JGit

Tags: java, git, github, jgit

How can I get all branches in a repository with JGit?
Let's take an [example repository](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen). As we can see, it has 5 branches.
[Here](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ListBranches.java) I found this example:

```
int c = 0;
List<Ref> call = new Git(repository).branchList().call();
for (Ref ref : call) {
    System.out.println("Branch: " + ref + " " + ref.getName() + " "
            + ref.getObjectId().getName());
    c++;
}
System.out.println("Number of branches: " + c);
```

But all I get is this:

```
Branch: Ref[refs/heads/master=d766675da9e6bf72f09f320a92b48fa529ffefdc] refs/heads/master d766675da9e6bf72f09f320a92b48fa529ffefdc
Number of branches: 1
Branch: master
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If it is the remote branches that you are missing, you have to set the `ListMode` of the `ListBranchCommand` to `ALL` or `REMOTE`. By default, the command returns only local branches.

```
new Git(repository).branchList().setListMode(ListMode.ALL).call();
```

Comment: I have updated the example in the jgit-cookbook to show this as well.

Answer (score 5):

I use the below method for git branches without cloning the repo using Jgit

This goes in the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.201506240215-r</version>
    </dependency>
```

Method

```
public static List<String> fetchGitBranches(String gitUrl)
            {
                Collection<Ref> refs;
                List<String> branches = new ArrayList<String>();
                try {
                    refs = Git.lsRemoteRepository()
                            .setHeads(true)
                            .setRemote(gitUrl)
                            .call();
                    for (Ref ref : refs) {
                        branches.add(ref.getName().substring(ref.getName().lastIndexOf("/")+1, ref.getName().length()));
                    }
                    Collections.sort(branches);
                } catch (InvalidRemoteException e) {
                    LOGGER.error(" InvalidRemoteException occured in fetchGitBranches",e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TransportException e) {
                    LOGGER.error(" TransportException occurred in fetchGitBranches",e);
                } catch (GitAPIException e) {
                    LOGGER.error(" GitAPIException occurred in fetchGitBranches",e);
                }
                return branches;
            }
```