# Fetching all Git branches programmatically with JGit

Tags: git, jgit

I am using [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) in a project and I would like to achieve the programmatic equivalent of a `git --fetch all`. The [JGit API Documentation](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.11.0.201803080745-r/apidocs/index.html) provides three [alternative fetch operations](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.11.0.201803080745-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/FetchCommand.html#setRefSpecs-java.lang.String...-) called `setRefSpecs(...)`. All alternatives require the developer to define the concrete `RefSpecs` to update.

I expect that I have to query the repository for all available `RefSpecs` and aggregate them for one combined fetch call (similar to [Getting all branches with JGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518782/getting-all-branches-with-jgit)
). However, I do not understand how to transform a `Ref` into a `RefSpec`. I would appreciate any pointer here.

Very related to this, I am also not sure how to prune local branches that have been deleted remotely (`fetch --prune`). Am I right to assume that setting `setRemoveDeletedRefs` to `true` achieves exactly this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the git fetch documentation, `--all` will fetch branches from all (configured) remotes.

JGit's `RemoteListCommand` can be used to get a list of all configured remotes. Fore each remote, you would need to fetch branches. I assume, the refspec fetch said branches is derived from the respective remote's configuration.

Using the JGit API, this would be

```java
Git git = ...
List<RemoteConfig> remotes = git.remoteList().call();
for(RemoteConfig remote : remotes) {
  git.fetch()
      .setRemote(remote.getName())
      .setRefSpecs(remote.getFetchRefSpecs())
      .call();
}
```

You can, of course, use your own refspec, for example `refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/<remote-name>/*` to synchronize all branches .

To answer your second question: yes, `FetchCommand::setRemoveDeletedRefs` is used to prune local branches, the equivalent of `--prune`.